# How to convert ros PointCloud2 to a pcl Pointcloud2 using only pcl 1.8?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

I am working with ros but I need some new features from pcl 1.8. That's why I include it like a system dependency using `find_package(PCL 1.8 Required)` and can't include any ros_pcl package, because I read in a mailinglist about this issue that mixing ros_pcl and standalone pcl is a bad idea.

Now I can't find a method how to convert a ros `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` pointcloud into a `pcl::PointCloud2` pointcloud. I only found `void pcl::toPCLPointCloud2 (const pcl::PointCloud< PointT >& cloud, pcl::PCLPointCloud2 & msg)` which has the wrong type and gives me a compilation error.

Now there is this function in the pcl_conversion package: `void pcl::fromROSMsg (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &cloud, pcl::PointCloud< T > &pcl_cloud)` and I did use it successfully just to try it out, but then couldn't use pcl 1.8 at the same time. Now my question is: Would it be the best to copy/implement the function `fromROSMsg` myself to be able to use 1.8 or is there a better way how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues regarding this, following hints may help you,

In CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

.
.
.

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Then add `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` into `target_link_libraries`.

To convert in 1.8, I used this way and it worked.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> in_cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg(in_msg, in_cloud);
```

where in_msg is a type of `const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&`.

Comment: Thank you, I resolved this issue a while ago and forgot to delete the question. I will accept this answer if others upvote it. I can't, because I can't confirm it and I will not be doing things with PCL soon.

Comment: does fromROSMsg copy the data?

Comment: @johannes_lalala  yeap, it transforms ros message into pcl defined type (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>)

Comment: is there any equivalent of pcl::fromROSMsg(in_msg, in_cloud); in python?

Comment: @darshanz you may try this https://answers.ros.org/question/202787/using-pointcloud2-data-getting-xy-points-in-python/